# Drag / sort images

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I can select multiple images and watch their preview, but I can't sort them out or drag them to change positions.
Can anyone help me implement this?
Thank you very much.

**Component ts**

```
files:any;
  urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    // this.urls = [];
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (this.files.length < 7) {

      for (let file of this.files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an angular library available called `ngx-drag-drop`. You can make use of that.

**npm link** => https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-drag-drop

**Stackblitz links:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-drag-and-drop-lists-5apzjp

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-drag-drop-test-ut3rj7

Comment: I will try to implement despite having some doubts

Comment: @Harry This is an very useful library for drag and drop in angular and I hope that the stackblitz links would be helpful. Happy Coding! Cheers :)

Comment: Already tried to implement, I had some difficulties because I am a beginner and I have 2 errors that I can not solve :( can you help me? I already updated the stackblitz link